# Can we pass static member variables to constructor to resolve unity?

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-container

i have an interface which is registered with a Class.
This class inherits a base class to whom i need to pass parameter while calling it's constructor.

```
In app.config
<register type="IA" mapTo="A">
      </register>
    

    objA=container.Resolve<IA>();
    
   public  Class B
    {
        public B(string text)
        {
        }
    }
    
   public  Class A : B , IA
    {
        static string text="hello";
        
        public A() : base(text)
        {
        }``
    }
```

Is this a good practice to pass static variable in constructor to resolve unity ?``
is there any other way of doing it ?

Note : if i want to pass the parameter from outside the class A, i will have to make changes in interface IA which is being used in many other parts of my project.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is required for configuration, I'd make an overload of the constructor that takes an `Options` parameter, which contains all the configuration in one strongly typed object:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(FooOptions options)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class FooOptions
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can register a static instance of the options, which is passed to all `Foo` instances. I'm not sure about Unity syntax, but it would probably look something like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(new FooOptions { Text = "hello" });
```